# Use existing PEM private key to sign data on iOS

Tags: iphone, rsa

I need to import an existing key into my app to use it with RSA encryption, I don't want to generate a new key.
I've read the apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html
But it doesn't seem to provide a way to import an existing PEM private key, it talks about creating them, but not about how to use an existing key.

Is this actually possible? Are there any API or Lib to do this? I don't need this for appstore, so don't be shy with responses if they are against the appstore rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I ended up using a version of OpenSSL compiled for iPhone:
https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Comment: i need a code snippet for importing PEM using this OpenSSL-for-iPhone lib please